# Trying to find a compatible replacement relay

Tags: relay

I'm a novice with electrical circuits though I am (slowly) with the aid of the YouTube and this fourm teaching myself how things work.

I have an opportunity to fix a broken microwave control panel and I have determined it's the low voltage relay (diagnostics were easy - it's physically broken).

My problem is the relay is "obsolete", but I have found what appears to be a compatible relay except for one key variable - the *coil resistance*.  Basically, the original relay had a coil resistance of 5ohms and the replacement has a resistance of 2.35kOhms

I don't know how this resistance comes into play in relation to the relay.  Can someone tell how this relevant to the functionality?

- Old relay:  [Fujitsu FTR-JRJC024W](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Fujitsu/FTR-JRJC024W/?qs=OjxD7yOTl1EKKq0ZKYmhyA==)
- New relay:  [Fujitsu JS-24-K](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Fujitsu/JS-24-K/?qs=pc5iSNpyspYVA7ueEya4Xg%3D%3D)

Messing up the control panel is not really a problem as I am using this as a learning exercise.  While my goal is to ultimately fix it, I won't be too broken up if I happen to let the magic smoke out of it either.

Answer (score 2):

It may be rare but possible and appears to be a Mouser Database error on the Obsolete p/n

When you see 3 orders of magnitude disparity, the cross check is Pd.

FTR-JRJC024W

- mouser   5 ohms 45 mW @24V  (computes to 25.9k =R=V^2/W)= X
- fujitsu  - 1100 ohms 530mW @24V  ( computes to 1087 ohms ) = √

Answer (score 1):

Coil resistance differences between similar relays is usually related to the operating voltage of the coils. That said - similar relays that have the same operating voltage can have different operating currents, and thus different resistance.

I mention this so that you ensure that both relays have the same coil voltage.

If the relays are otherwise identical, you should have no problem swapping in the new relay.